# unwanted space in table cells

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 3 rows and 3 columns. The 1st and 3rd rows span all 3 columns. It consists of 7 images, 1 on the 1st row, 3 on the 2nd, and 3 on the 3rd.

My issue is with the left cell on the 2nd row and the 3rd row. On the 2nd row, the left cell has what appears to be about 6 pixels of space between the left border of the table and the image. The image has no extra space as part of the image, the css I wrote specifies no margin on the table or cell, no padding or border-spacing on the table or cell and no padding on the image. I don't know where this space is coming from, or how to get rid of it.

On the 3rd row, all 3 images are contained within a single cell spanning the width of the 3 cells. The images are centered and are supposed to be the height of the row. Each image has 5 pixels of spacing to the left and right, but no spacing to the top or bottom. They are also supposed to be middle aligned vertically. The center image, smaller than the other 2, should be in the middle between the top and bottom of the two other images (which are both the same size), but instead it is centered between the top and bottom of the cell, and there is about 6 pixels of space between the bottom of the images and the bottom of the cell. Again, the table cell is no padding and no border-spacing.

I have created a jsfiddle to show it, but the images are not there since the page is not online anywhere. The 3rd row text from the alt tag doesn't show the space between the bottom of the text and the bottom of the cell, but the left cell on the 2nd row shows a space before the S that begins the alt text of that image. There is no space in the text at that position, so I believe it is showing the unwarranted space I am referring to.

What can I do to get rid of this unnecessary and unwanted spacing? Also, please forgive my CSS writing style. I am still somewhat new to CSS and am still learning it. Also, again, the 1st row and the right image of the second row display as they should. The middle cell of the 2nd row wasn't centered until I specified a width to the left cell.

Here is an image of the table, and [here is the link](https://jsfiddle.net/94vsLykf/) to the jsfiddle that contains the html and css for that table. OK, seems I have to place code in this message, so here's the CSS and the HTML as it occurs in the jsfiddle:

[image: image of the table]

CSS

```
  .img {
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 5px 0;
  }
  .img2 {
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
  table {
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    border-spacing:0;
  }
  .table1 {
    width:100%;
  }
  .table2 {
    margin:auto;
  }
  .tr1 {
    vertical-align:top;
  }
  .td1 {
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    border-spacing:0;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    width:284px;
    border:1px solid;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:left;
    font-family:Calibri;
    font-size:1em;
  }
  .td2 {
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    border-spacing:0;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    border:1px solid;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Calibri;
    font-size:1em;
  }
  .td3 {
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    border-spacing:0;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    border:1px solid;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:right;
    font-family:Calibri;
    font-size:1em;
  }
```

HTML

```
<TABLE class="table1 table2">
  <TR><TD class="td2" colspan=3>
    <A href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000IU3YA0" rel="nofollow noreferrer"
     target="_blank"><IMG class="img2" src="Images/Tofu/468_60.gif"
     width=468 height=60
     alt="Soundtrack horizontal banner"
     title="Soundtrack horizontal banner"></A>
  </TD></TR><TR class="tr1"><TD class="td1"> 
    <A href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000IU3YA0" rel="nofollow noreferrer"
     target="_blank"><IMG class="img2" src="Images/Tofu/120-240.gif"
     width=120 height=240
     alt="Soundtrack wide vertical banner"
     title="Soundtrack wide vertical banner"></A>
  </TD><TD class="td2">
    <A href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000IU3YA0" rel="nofollow noreferrer"
     target="_blank"><IMG class="img2" src="Images/Tofu/120_90.gif"
     width=120 height=90
     alt="Soundtrack small banner"
     title="Soundtrack small banner"></A>
  </TD><TD  class="td3">
    <A href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000IU3YA0" rel="nofollow noreferrer"
     target="_blank"><IMG class="img2" src="Images/Tofu/95.jpg"
     width=95 height=95
     alt="Soundtrack square banner"
     title="Soundtrack square banner"></A>
  </TD></TR><TR class="tr1"><TD class="td2" colspan=3>
    <A href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000IU3YA0" rel="nofollow noreferrer"
     target="_blank"><IMG class="img" src="Thumbnails/Tofu/icon_50.gif"
     width=50 height=60
     alt="Soundtrack promotion button"
     title="Soundtrack promotion button"></A>
    <A href="http://www.tofurecords.com/artists.php?artistid=ffxii"
     target="_blank"><IMG class="img" src="Thumbnails/Tofu/TOF033_cover.jpg"
     width=30 height=30
     alt="Soundtrack promotion button"
     title="Soundtrack promotion button"></A>
    <A href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000IU3YA0" rel="nofollow noreferrer"
     target="_blank"><IMG class="img" src="Thumbnails/Tofu/website_icon.gif"
     width=50 height=60
     alt="Soundtrack official website button"
     title="Soundtrack official website button"></A>
  </TD></TR>
</TABLE>
```

Edit: I went to the jsfiddle after posting this and the space on the 2nd row left cell isn't there now. I don't know why it changed when I didn't change anything.

Comment: Please use the complete paths to the images in your jsfiddle or use [https://dummyimage.com/](https://dummyimage.com/).

Comment: It looks the way you want in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/27vLauf9/5/)

Comment: I will look at dummyimage. This site is currently only on my harddrive, so the images can't be directly linked. That was a concern to me, but I didn't know what to do about it

Comment: use the jsfiddle I just linked for you that has dummy images

Comment: I just added dummy images to the one I made earlier. Not only is it displaying correctly, but I had to reduce the width I added to the left cell on the 2nd row from 284px to 204px for the middle image to center above the bottom images. I don't understand what is happening. I didn't change anything about my CSS, and if you look at the image I posted in my original post, you can see the space on the left of the left image and below the bottom images. any clue what is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to post this as an answer because it deserves to be noted. Always make sure you check for extraneous space characters at the end of a line. If it's not intended to be there it will cause you problems with display. The issues with my table were two-fold and had different corrections.

For the left cell on the second row it was simply a space character immediately after the closing bracket (>) of the TD that was causing the space between the border of the cell and the image.

For the 3rd row, it was transparent background on the bottom of the images. The text those areas contained is black in color and you couldn't see it without very close examination. The fix was to set background-color:aliceblue; (in my case because I prefer aliceblue over white) on the images. The middle cell of the 2nd row was still off-center from the images in the 1st and 3rd rows, so I still had to use width:284px; on the left cell to cause the middle cell to be centered.

Answer (score -1):

The `<table>` is a really bad way to do it. Here an alternative way to do it.
I've used the Grid and if you need help click [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) for a complete guide to Grid

HTML

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="row1">
        <div class="Soundtrack">
            <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000IU3YA0" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank">
                <img id="img2" src="Images/Tofu/468_60.gif" alt="Soundtrack horizontal banner" title="Soundtrack horizontal banner" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
        <div class="Soundtrack">
            <div>
                <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000IU3YA0" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank">
                    <img class="img2" src="Images/Tofu/120-240.gif" style="width: 120px; height: 240px;" alt="Soundtrack wide vertical banner" title="Soundtrack wide vertical banner" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000IU3YA0" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank">
                    <img class="img2" src="Images/Tofu/120-240.gif" style="width: 120px; height: 240px;" alt="Soundtrack wide vertical banner" title="Soundtrack wide vertical banner" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000IU3YA0" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank">
                    <img class="img2" src="Images/Tofu/120-240.gif" style="width: 120px; height: 240px;" alt="Soundtrack wide vertical banner" title="Soundtrack wide vertical banner" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row3">
        <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000IU3YA0" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank">
            <img class="img2" src="Images/Tofu/120-240.gif" style="width: 120px; height: 240px;" alt="Soundtrack wide vertical banner" title="Soundtrack wide vertical banner" />
        </a>

        <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000IU3YA0" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank">
            <img class="img2" src="Images/Tofu/120-240.gif" style="width: 120px; height: 240px;" alt="Soundtrack wide vertical banner" title="Soundtrack wide vertical banner" />
        </a>

        <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000IU3YA0" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank">
            <img class="img2" src="Images/Tofu/120-240.gif" style="width: 120px; height: 240px;" alt="Soundtrack wide vertical banner" title="Soundtrack wide vertical banner" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,
body,
.grid-container {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.grid-container {
    margin: 12px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 0.9fr 1.1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 1px 1px;
    grid-template-areas: "row1 row1 row1" "row2 row2 row2" "row3 row3 row3";
}

.row1 {
    grid-area: row1;
    justify-items: center;
}
.row1 > div {
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
}
.row2 {
    grid-area: row2;
}
.Soundtrack {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    justify-items: center;
}
.row2 > div > div {
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
}
.Soundtrack > div {
    border: 2px solid gray;
    width: 100%;
    border-right: 0px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.row3 {
    grid-area: row3;
    border-top: 2px solid gray;
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-gap: 30px;
}
```

Comment: You have simply showed him a basic grid.  You've changed the heights and widths of his images.  Show a working example with the same positioning of the elements that he wants as in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/27vLauf9/5/)

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to help. I know I'll probably get flack for this, but I never had good luck with DIVs. TABLEs have always worked best for me. This is the first time I've had this problem. As soon as I started changing things from attributes and FONT tags to CSS I started running into issues of making the pages look the same. For the most part I have succeeded, though a few pages look slightly different if you were to compare the CSS version with the old version. And this is the first time I've had unwanted space in table cells that I couldn't get rid of.

Comment: If it is possible to draw what layer you want it would make it bit easier

Comment: I don't know what you mean. It is a single table with 3 rows. The first row is a single cell spanning the width of the table. The second row defines that width by creating 3 cells. the third row also spans the width of the table. I don't see any layering going on here. Would it help if I split the tags apart so each TR and TD was on a separate line?

Comment: What i ment was creating the UI with www.figma.com .

Comment: Ps: you supposed to write tags in lowercase like <td>

Comment: HTML and CSS are case-insensitive That means there is no rule requiring either. I used to use all uppercase on tags and attributes. Then I decided it was easier to tell them apart if I used lowercase on the attributes. That proved to be true. I did a few pages in all lowercase and had the same issue with telling the tags apart from the attributes, so I have stayed with uppercase tags and lowercase attributes. In the CSS I use all lowercase because it isn't as big of a problem to see what I wrote, and in the HTML it flows with the attributes better for the class names to be lowercase.

Comment: If you were to look at one of my pages, you would see that the first two lines are:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML lang="en">

Note the HTML tag is uppercase and the html attribute is lowercase.